# How to run a Python file in Visual Studio code from the terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have tried to run a pretty simple code

```
x = input("What's x? ")
y = input("What's y? ")

z= int(x) + int(y)

print (z)
```

But, when I try to run that code from the terminal writing "name_of_the_file.py", I find this error:

"The term "name_of_the_file.py" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

If a right click on where you write the code, and then click on "run python file in terminal", it runs!

I am taking the CS50P, and I see that this should be possible because the teacher is able to do that. What am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: Try python name_of_the_file.py.

Answer (score 2):

Click the play button to run the code, watch the terminal and you can see that it is using the command `& c:/WorkSpace/pytest11/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/WorkSpace/pytest11/main.py` to run the code.

[image]

So if you need to manually type commands in the terminal to run the code. You can directly copy the above command.

If you use a virtual environment or have system environment variables configured, you can simplify the python path with the following command

```
python main.py
```

*PS: `main.py` is my script file name, you need to modify it to your own file name.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do follow below steps

1. Open terminal in VS code
2. go to directory where you have .py file located  using cd command
3. run command in terminal (eg. python3 file_name.py

   Me@MyMacBook-Air string % python3 str_to_int.py

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try to follow these steps:

1. Create a folder where you want your script to run
2. Open the folder using VS Code: File -> Open Folder
3. Create your script and save it in the folder
4. Open a new terminal: Terminal -> New Terminal
5. Type the command: python name_of_the_file.py
6. If it doesn't work, try: py name_of_the_file.py
7. If you are using a python 3 version, try: python3 name_of_the_file.py

My output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

1. open terminal in vscode.
2. check the directory in terminal, it must be same path to where you file is saved.
3. run command in terminal :

   python3 name_of_the_file.py

Answer (score 0):

Use `python filename.py`.

This command should work.

If you're utilizing Python 3 and have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed on your system, you may need to use **`python3`** instead of merely **`python`**:

`python3 filename.py`